# Random sample of boolean vector

Tags: r

I have a input vector `vi` with boolean values.  I want to take a random sample of size `n` from the vector where the value is true, so the final vector `vf` has these properties

1. The lengths of the vectors are equal
   `length(vf) == length(v0)`
2. `vf` has `n` true values
   `n==sum(vf)`
3. The true values in `vf` cannot be more than those in `v0`
   n <= sum(v0)
4. All the true values in `vf` are also true in `vi`

The vectors represents a selection of rows in a data frame, and this implements a stratified sample.  So far I figured out how to use `which()` to get the row numbers, to use `sample()` to get a random sample, but the last part is recreating the boolean vector.  There is probably a more elegant way?

For example:

`n <- 1`

`v0 <- c(T,T,F,F)`

`vf <- c(T,F,F,F)`

Comment: Is `length(vf) == length(v0)` and `n <= sum(v0)` then?

Comment: Tommy: yes, the lengths are exactly equal, and the number of true values in `vf` cannot be greater, so I would use sampling without replacement.

Comment: Are you just trying to get a random sample of rows from a data frame? I'm finding it hard to understand what you are trying to do. It would help if you could add an example.

Comment: @Seth: It's a little more complicated than just a random sample: it's more like a random sample _of a subset_.  As a little more background, this a step in my implementation of oversampling as described in the book "Mastering Data Mining" (page 197). The vector `v0` represents the rows in a data frame which have a negative response, and I need to reduce the negative responses because there are too many.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one solution:

```
# Make up some vector v0 and choose n
v0 <- rep(c(F,T,F), 5)
n <- 3


# The actual code
x <- which(v0)
vf <- logical(length(v0))
vf[x[sample.int(length(x), n)]] <- TRUE


# Finally validate the result
identical(length(vf), length(v0)) # TRUE
all(v0[vf])  # TRUE
sum(vf) == n # TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

You changed the requirements materially. My new suggestion works by randomly selecting the right number of TRUE-indices to set to FALSE:

```
vf <- vi; vf[sample( which(vi), size=sum(vi)-n)] <- FALSE

# Console
> vi <- sample(c(TRUE,FALSE),size=20, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.9, 0.1) )
> vf <- vi; vf[sample( which(vi), size=sum(vi)-10)] <- FALSE
> sum(vf)
[1] 10
```